# Is it possible to increase my downloading speed on IDM?

Tags: download, speed, internet-connection

I'm using 2g mobile  service for internet so speed is very low. I got the 20-30 Kbs downloading on IDM and same time its gone under the 20 Kbs. So my question is there is nay way to stable the downloading speed and is there any possible way to speed up the download more than I'm getting.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's 20KB/s == 20x8 == 160Kbps, **not** 20Kbps.

Next, you're on 2G/EDGE network and 160Kbps on an EDGE network is pretty reasonable/good.

Finally, no there's no way to increase the speed unless you switch over to 3G. You're getting the max. out of your connection

Comment: So is it possible to make its speed all the time over than 20 kbps.